# Sending a mail with hebrew content

Tags: php

I'm trying to send an email with an hebrew content but I can't get it right.. that's the header that I use:

```
$headers = "From: $from" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1";
```

For example, if I want to send:

```
איזה יום יפה היום
```

And the result I get instead of hebrew text is:

```
×˜×§×¡×˜: ×©×“×’×©×“×’×©×“×’×©×“×’
```

Comment: What's the text above supposed to look like (for comparison)?

Comment: An hebrew text for exmaple "איזה יום יפה היום"

Comment: Probably better using `UTF-8` Charset instead of `ISO-8859-1`

Comment: @ImriPersiado: Thanks. I've edited your post for completeness.

Comment: According to [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859#The_Parts_of_ISO.2FIEC_8859], the encoding for hebrew would be ISO-8859-8, not ISO-8859-1. Anyway, UTF-8 might also be a good idea.

Comment: @Abrixas2 I think you should post it as an answer if it's correct, well researched =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving out with this headers:

```
$headers = "From: $from" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859#The_Parts_of_ISO.2FIEC_8859), the ISO/IEC 8859 series of standards define hebrew characters in part 8, not part 1. Thus, you must specify

```
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-8";
```

instead of

```
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1";
```

in your code.

Anyway, it might be a good idea to use the UTF-8 encoding:

```
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
```

This allows you to send e-mails containing characters from different scripts or use special characters, eg. math characters.